# Update to API 27 and a strange thing happened to the CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

After I Update my project to API27(compileSdkVersion) and something strange happened.

Please see this picture :

my project screen shot

[image]

In this picture,you can see a strange line under my `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

I guess the height of the line is as high as the statusbar.

And I create a new project to test this condition.

[Github Gist - test project source code](https://gist.github.com/fsmytsai/c4f3e257bf99d7aa08508d054372cc3c)

I found this condition exists only API26 and API27

test project screen shot(API27)

[image]

The same code in API25 and lower is no that strange line

test project screen shot(API25)

[image]

Anyone can help me to fix it on API 27?

Comment: Could you please show us your layout code.

Comment: Here is my code
https://gist.github.com/fsmytsai/c4f3e257bf99d7aa08508d054372cc3c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this issues by setting up the layout_height of the CollapsingToolbarLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@color/purple"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

Instead of 

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/purple"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Hope it works for you!